# Add new subscriber to list in mailchimp

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp

I was wondering about how can I add new subscriber to mailchimp list using asp.net.

Here is the code I have which do nothing in that issue:

```
var entry = new Dictionary<string, object>();
entry.Add( "FNAME", "x");
entry.Add( "LNAME", "y" );
var lsi=new listSubscribeInput(apiKey,listId,"xyz@abc.com",entry);
var ls=new listSubscribe(lsi);
ls.Execute();
```

Comment: And finally I can solve the issue, it is in the PerceptiveMCAPI Documentation attached with the API using the listBatchSubscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest API (1.3) you can add a subscriber to a list using:

```
// Subscribe the provided email to a list. 
listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, array merge_vars,
    string email_type, bool double_optin, bool update_existing,
    bool replace_interests, bool send_welcome);
```

See [MailChimp API](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/1.3/#listrelated).

Comment: Using the latest API(2.0) this would be: subscribe(string apikey, string id, struct email, struct merge_vars, string email_type, bool double_optin, bool update_existing, bool replace_interests, bool send_welcome)

Answer (score 1):

In C# the implementation would be something like this:

```
        var options = new List.SubscribeOptions{DoubleOptIn = true,EmailType = List.EmailType.Html,SendWelcome = false};
        var merges = new List<List.Merges> { new List.Merges("john@provider.com", List.EmailType.Html) { { "FNAME", "John" }, { "LNAME", "Smith" } } };
        var mcApi = new MCApi(apiKey, false);

        mcApi.ListBatchSubscribe(listId, merges, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me.
Add into References MailChimp.Net.dll
than you can define an interface like

```
IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpApiKey"].ToString());
```

than you can add or update your client in your MailChimp list

```
                Member m = await manager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpListId"].ToString(), new Member { EmailAddress = _email, EmailType = "html", Status = Status.Pending});
            m = await manager.Members.AddOrUpdateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpListId"].ToString(), new Member { EmailAddress = _email, EmailType = "html", Status = Status.Subscribed });
```

Hope this helps...